# Make Button Visibility Hidden on click from another button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Im trying to set Visibility property on my button to Hidden by click from another button. That code works pretty well:

```
<Button x:Name="Button">             
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HideBar, Path=IsPressed}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Like you can see above, `IsPressed` in `Path` property on binding works pretty ok, but the button is hidden only when i have mouse button pressed down. How to make button visibility set to Hidden permanently after click on "Hidebar" button that is mentioned in `Binding ElementName=HideBar` ? Im tyring to work with MVVM but in my opinien DataTriggers are simpler for coding view.

Comment: One way to do it is changing `HideBar` button to a check box with a button style, then chance the trigger path to `IsChecked`. That way, it'll look like a button but when pressed it stays pressed, also the user can see if the button is enabled or not

Comment: Now things start to be more complicated, beacuse i want to have two Bars for hiding and showing. When i click HideBar buttons starts to be hidden, but when i click ShowBar buttons starts to be visible. @Magnetron could you propose an example for what you mentioned about?

Comment: You could have a boolean property in your ViewModel which is then bound to the data trigger and the `HideBar` & `ShowBar`. I could show you how to do this if you are unsure

Comment: I Found a solution after your comment, it was really helpful. But now i have a little problem with Button style. After using `<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">` i had a fancy mouse event (when i moving around button coulour of button getting to be a little lighter with opacity) but when i rewrite it to Toggle Button with the same Button Style it is static, it wont change after i click it or moving mouse on it. Maybe you know the solution? i can post code here

Comment: @metadon789 See if creating another style changing the `TargetType` from `Button` to `ToggleButton` works

Comment: Yes, it works pretty well! But the button named `HideBar` even if i set the same ToggleButton style from Button Style it is a little diffrent. From Button style when i moving up mouse on buttons it starts to be a little opacity + it is getting a little lighter in colour. When i set the same style in Toggle Button, it dont have that fancy features like button click / moving mouse on it events.

Comment: @metadon789 sorry, I don't know then. Maybe you could ask another question and someone can answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out you don't need to change the checkbox style to be based on a button, as there is a toggle button in WPF:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="HideBar"  Content="Click"/>
<Button x:Name="Button" Content="Testing">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HideBar, Path=IsChecked}"
                     Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Check comment on my original post please